# Garbage being printed when using strcpy

Tags: c, parsing, text, malloc, strncpy

I have a function that will parse some data coming in. My problem is that after using strncpy I get some garbage when I try to print it. I try using malloc to make the char array the exact size.

Code:

```
void parse_data(char *unparsed_data)
{
char *temp_str;
char *pos;
char *pos2;
char *key;
char *data;
const char newline = '\n';

int timestamp = 0;

temp_str = (char*)malloc(strlen(unparsed_data));

g_print("\nThe original string is: \n%s\n",unparsed_data);


//Ignore the first two lines
pos = strchr(unparsed_data, newline);
strcpy(temp_str, pos+1);
pos = strchr(temp_str, newline);
strcpy(temp_str, pos+1);

//Split the line in two; The key name and the value
pos = strchr(temp_str, ':'); // ':' divides the name from the value
pos2 = strchr(temp_str, '\n'); //end of the line
key = (char*)malloc((size_t)(pos-temp_str)-1); //allocate enough memory
data = (char*)malloc((size_t)(pos2-pos)-1);

strncpy(key, temp_str, (size_t)(pos-temp_str));
strncpy(data, pos + 2, (size_t)(pos2-pos));

timestamp = atoi(data);

g_print("size of the variable \"key\" = %d or %d\n", (size_t)(pos-temp_str), strlen(key));
g_print("size of the variable \"data\" = %d or %d\n", (size_t)(pos2-pos), strlen(data));

g_print("The key name is %s\n",key);
g_print("The value is %s\n",data);
g_print("End of Parser\n");
  }
```

Output:

```
The original string is: 
NEW_DATAa_PACKET
Local Data Set 16-byte Universal Key
Time Stamp (microsec): 1319639501097446
Frame Number: 0
Version: 3
Angle (deg): 10.228428

size of the variable "key" = 21 or 22
size of the variable "data" = 18 or 21
The key name is Time Stamp (microsec)
The value is 1319639501097446
F32
End of Parser
```

Run it again:

```
  The original string is: 
  NEW_DATAa_PACKET
  Local Data Set 16-byte Universal Key
  Time Stamp (microsec): 1319639501097446
  Frame Number: 0
  Version: 3
  Angle (deg): 10.228428

  size of the variable "key" = 21 or 25
  size of the variable "data" = 18 or 18
  The key name is Time Stamp (microsec)ipe 
  The value is 1319639501097446
  F
  End of Parser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `strncpy(data, pos + 2, (size_t)(pos2-pos));` doesn't add a terminating `\0` character at the end of the string. Therefore when you try to print it later, `printf()` prints your whole data string and whatever is in the memory right after it, until it reaches zero - that's the garbate you're getting. You need to explicitly append zero at the end of your data. It's also needed for `atoi()`.

**Edit:**
You need to allocate one more byte for your `data`, and write a terminating character there. `data[len_of_data] = '\0'`. Only after that it becomes a valid C string and you can use it for `atoi()` and `printf()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I add the terminating character at the end?

Comment: Basically you need to allocate one more byte for your `data`, and write a terminating character there. `data[len_of_data] = '\0'`. Only after that it becomes a C string and you can use it for `atoi()` and `printf()`.

Answer (score 5):

Your results are because `strncpy` does not put a null character at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to malloc() +1 byte for a string, so it can append the zero when you do strcpy(), but the strncpy will not append zero as well you need a extra byte for it.

Answer (score 1):

One problem: What if there's no newline?

Undefined behaviour:

```
pos = strchr(temp_str, newline);
strcpy(temp_str, pos+1);
```

The source and destination of `strcpy` must not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember in allocating space for a string to add one byte for the terminating  '\0' character. You have to be careful with `strncpy`, especially if you are used to using `strcpy`, `strcat`, or `sprintf`. Those three functions terminate the string with '\0'. `strncpy` copies a number of bytes that you specify, and makes no assumption of terminating the string.

You assume that responsibility by making sure you place a '\0' at the end of the character buffer to which you copied. That means you have to know the starting the position and the length of the copy and put a '\0' one byte past the sum of the starting position and length.

I chose to solve a sample problem slightly differently, but it still involves knowing the length of what I copied.

In this case, I use `strncpy` to take the first 9 characters from `pcszTestStr1` and 
copy them to szTestBuf. Then, I use strcpy -- which terminates the string with a zero --
to append the new part of the sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int n;
int argv_2;

char szTestBuf[100] = {0};
char * pcszTestStr1 = 
"This is a very long, long string to be used in a C example, OK?";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;

    printf("The following sentence is too long.\n%s\n", pcszTestStr1);
    strncpy(szTestBuf, pcszTestStr1, 9);
    strcpy(szTestBuf + 9, " much shorter sentence.");
    printf("%s\n", szTestBuf); 

    return rc;
}
```

Here's the output of running test.c compiled `gcc -o test test.c`.

```
cnorton@hiawatha:~/scratch$ ./test
The following sentence is too long.
This is a very long, long string to be used in a C example, OK?
This is a much shorter sentence.
cnorton@hiawatha:~/scratch$
```