# string copy issue in C

Tags: c

in the below program I need to reverse string without using library function. But the output after copying prints some garbage value. Can anyone kindly help me in figuring it out?
[image: Please find the code and output]

Comment: First thing you need to do is define a character limit and stick with it, otherwise you can expect a segmentation fault. Also, its more helpful to post code as text on the screen instead of a picture of half a computer program.

Comment: 1. `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of the file. 2. Fix compiler errors. 3. If further questions, please copy/paste code as text, not images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Garbage being printed when using strcpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161609/garbage-being-printed-when-using-strcpy)

Comment: How the heck did this compile?? Even with the missing `#include`, there should have been compile errors with `str1[i]` and `str2[j]`!!

Comment: You must fix any compiler messages before worrying about the output of yourprogram. If you don't see any messages then you need to figure out where to look in your IDE to see the messages.

Comment: Please don't paste the image of the code unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`str1` and `str2` must be `char` arrays large enough to hold the strings.
For your simplistic example, `char str1[128], str2[128];` should do.

You must initialize `j` to the length of `str1` before the loop and null terminate `str2` with `str2[j--] = '\0';` before the loop:

```
for (j = 0; str1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
    continue;
}
str2[j--] = '\0';
for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++, j--) {
    str2[j] = str1[i];
}
```

Comment: but `strlen` requires string.h library, OP wants to do without using it

Comment: @ch3rub7: you are correct, I removed the `<string.h>` dependency.

Comment: terminating str2 with null produces desired result. if str2 is not terminated with null, the output is like "ayvid garbage value divya"(as in output screen in pic one). I need to know how come after garbage value it prints the original string again at the end. Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: @divya: I'm not sure what code you are referring to: the code in the picture is broken, it should not compile.  If you do not null terminate your string, the code invokes undefined behavior, leading to erratic behavior.  A precise explanation for observed behavior in such circumstances is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

str2 should be assigned with null character '\0' after the string reversal in for loop.

```
for(j=strlen(str1);str1[i]!='\0';i++,j--)
        str2[j-1]=str1[i];
str2[i]='\0';
```

Comment: if str2 is not terminated with null, the output is like "ayvid garbage value divya"(as in output screen in pic one). I need to know how come after garbage value it prints the original string again at the end.