# Trash using memcpy

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I'm using memcpy to copy a specific number of chars from a char array to a char *. But when I read the char * have always trash in the end.

I'm using libssh2 lib to send commands to my raspberry pi and receive the output.

`libssh2_channel_read` will return the number of chars of the output `int x` and the output text will be on the `char buffer[32]`.

Code I'm using:

```
char buffer[32];
int x = libssh2_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
char * output = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*x);
memcpy(output, buffer, x-2); // x - 2 because of "\r\n"
libssh2_channel_free(channel);
channel = NULL;
cout << output << endl;
```

Example of output:

```
0══²²²²
```

I only want the `0`

Comment: So you are not copying the string terminator `\0`?

Comment: That is not the problem but don't cast the return of `malloc` as there is no need and may hide problems, see [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/8051589) why.

Comment: have you checked the actual value of `x`?

Comment: @AndreKampling the answer you link says that one does not need to cast, but nothing about the cast being a real problem

Comment: @tobi303: As I said it is not the problem... But you may hide things wich could bring trouble.

Comment: @AndreKampling - The link is for `c` - not `c++`

Comment: @AndreKampling sorry I misread your "That is not" as refering to the comment before...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Garbage being printed when using strcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161609/garbage-being-printed-when-using-strcpy).  It uses `strcpy` instead of `memcpy` but it s the same thing basically.

Comment: @AndreKampling - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt

Comment: @NathanOliver No! Because I not working with strings during the copy (where is the question), only in the end.

Comment: @4386427 That's correct!!! c++ need cast

Comment: @4386427: Wow thank you didn't know that!

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: "copy ... from a `char` array to a `char*`" -- you're in deep trouble. You cannot copy characters to a pointer. You **must** copy them to **another array of `char`**, typically one that's **pointed to** by a `char*`. A pointer is not an array and an array is not a pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know that. Everyone understood when I said "copy from char array to a char *" I don't mean literaly like x = y. Sorry if my english is not that good xD

Comment: @Samega7Cattac -- your English is fine. My point is that the **difference** between a pointer and an array is extremely important, and beginners often overlook it. There are quite a few posts where (unlike yours) someone just uses a pointer that doesn't point anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to C++.

You are copying the values you care about but not the terminating '\0' character. Assuming `x` is valid (that is: x > 3 and x <= sizeof(buffer)) you can say:

```
output[x - 2] = '\0';
```

after the call to `memcpy()` and you should get what you expect.

However: when you're dealing with communications and buffers like this you need to be careful and check everything.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `output[x-2]` ?

Comment: Correct!! if I do `output[x - 2] = '\0'` will work! Why `x - 2`? Because of the `\r\n` in the end of all commands.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, indeed!

Comment: @Samega7Cattac - because a C-style string requires a termination char with the value zero. So if you have `abcdef\r\n` and only copies `abcdef` into the new buffer using `memcpy`, you don't have the termination. So you must add `'\0'` after the `memcpy` to make it a valid C-style string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't be using raw arrays and `memcpy` and the like here.

You are probably better off with the containers from the C++ standard library:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string
- [Directly write into char* buffer of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39200665/1025391)

Example:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(32);
int x = libssh2_channel_read(channel, &buffer[0], buffer.size());
// probably x will be smaller or equal the current size of the buffer
buffer.resize(x);
// if it's a string, why not have it as a std::string
std::string data(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
std::cout << data << '\n';
```

Comment: This does not remove the `\r\n` at the end of the data

Comment: @NathanOliver Resizing a std::string or a std::vector is trivial. Stripping the string of trailing whitespace is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::string:

```
char buffer[32];
int x = libssh2_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
std::string output{ buffer, buffer + x - 2 };
libssh2_channel_free(channel);
channel = NULL;
cout << output << endl;
```

Comment: Can you explain why `std::string output{ buffer, buffer + x - 2 };`?

Comment: `buffer + x` one after the end of data, `- 2` because of "\r\n"

Comment: @Samega7Cattac You give it the (address of) the first byte you _want_ and of the first byte you _don't_ want (one past the end less two for the CRLF).

Comment: @manni66 Ok, now I understand. But I need it to be char * because of other functions and converting string to char * sometimes can go bad